# Flexibility with eager loading huge object graphs, NHibernate HQL TOP N in SQL

Tags: entity-framework, nhibernate, poco, eager-loading, object-graph

I need to pass POCO Domain objects (eagerly loaded). Having analyzed both Entity Framework and NHibernate, I can't find a solution!

Analyzing the underlying SQL and queries by NHibernate, I discovered that

```
ISession.CreateQuery (string HQL).SetMaxResults(N)
```

does not implement `TOP N` in SQL, but always downloads all of the data to .NET and only then takes the subset (so stupid)

So how can I send complex queries to huge tables?

`ICreteria` (`SetMaxResults` implemented in SQL) and `IQueryOver` (`Take()` impl in SQL) are inflexible, e.g eager loading would only be possible ONLY with left join. also custom subqueries, top, filtration or order by etc. obviously the flexibility of SQL is on much higher level.

Entity Framework is fluid and seems to make the magic happen, but SOO-O DAMN SLOW!

The best flexible eager loading I can think of, after week's work, is HQL with `TOP N` implemented by a preloaded `IList` and `SetParameterList`.

Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I might be way off (I can't check the answer right now) but can't you pass the "top X" in the query itself. Something like:

```
ISession.CreateQuery("select top" + n + " ...");
```